# How to take text area value and put it into hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a "web page" for employees that will be hosted locally on a drive for people.

We have a ticketing system that runs in a browser that allows us to add tickets, find tickets, etc etc.

I am creating a quick homepage for people to use so they can quickly find their tickets without clicking around on the portal and trying to understand the search functions.

to do this I have a hyperlink but need to change the url to include what is in a text area.

I believe php would work fine for this but it won't be hosted on a web server do not able to run PHP. I also believe there is a with Java/Html.

```
<a url="ticketsonline.co.uk/<username>/tickets">
```

I need  to be whatever the user types into the text area.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to store the base url in a variable then append what ever is the value of the text area to it and then set href value of the link to the resulted value

```js
var baseLink = "ticketsonline.co.uk/";
function changeLink(){
  document.getElementById("searchLink").href =  baseLink + document.getElementById("searchText").value
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="searchLink">Search</a>
<br>
<textarea id="searchText"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="changeLink()">Update Link</button>
```